# installing rvm on lion

Tags: ruby, terminal, osx-lion

How to install RVM on lion, I am trying this command in terminal

```
curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm
```

After this command executed it gives me a lot of text in terminal, the text is ending with this statement

```
chmod +x ./scripts/install

# Now we run the RVM installer.
./scripts/install ${flags[*]} --prefix "$rvm_prefix" --path "$rvm_path"
```

After it finish executing I tried rvm command but its giving me error command not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from:
http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyversionmanager/ss/Installing-Ruby-On-Snow-Leopard-With-Rvm_6.htm

> Now that the RVM scripts are installed, you need to load them every
>   time your start a new Bash session. This is achieved by adding a line
>   to the end of your ~/.bash_profile file. You can add this line with
>   your favorite text editor, or by using the cat command. Just hit
>   Ctrl-D after you've typed the line and it will write that line to the
>   file and return you to the bash prompt.

```
$ cat >>~/.bash_profile
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you running only `curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm` in terminal? This only displays the content of the script.

If you want to install it you need to run something like this(assuming you are using bash):

```
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```